# "m_db unload" command not returning any value in AbInitio

Tags: parameters, etl, graphical-programming, ab-initio

I am using **m_db** command to load the value from a table to a parameter in **`AbInitio graph`**.

But its not showing any value. I also run it in Unix but still its not showing any value.

The command is (enclosed in back ticks):

```
`m_db unload myoracle.dbc - select "select name from employee"`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem. There were two mistakes I was doing:

First I was not **committing** the data after insertion in SQL server.

Second I was using parameter interpretation as **substitution** but now I have changed it to **shell**.

Any other suggestion are most welcomed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try: m_db unload myoracle.dbc -select "select name from employee" -column_delimeter "|"